# Understanding and solving why this un-instantiated property produces an error?

Tags: javascript, object, instantiation, typeof

An object I have instantiated ***(Enemies)*** looks for the property of another object ***(shotArr[0].x)*** that may or may not exist. It tries to do this through the `this.detect = function()`

```
function Enemies(x,y,w,h) {
  this.x = x; this.w = w;
  this.y = y; this.h = h;
    this.draw = function(){ //how to paint
      ctx.shadowBlur= 0;//  shadow Blur
      ctx.shadowColor= 'red';
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(200, 0, 0)';
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    }
    this.detect = function() {
      if (typeof (shotArr[0].x) === 'undefined') {
        return console.log('no bullets exist at the moment');
      } else {
        return shotArr[0].x;
      }
    }
    this.move = function() { //animation behavior
      this.y++;
    }
    this.send = function(){ //send to canvas
      this.draw();
      this.move();
      this.detect();
    }
}
```

Unless the user takes a shot by hitting the space key, then the array is empty and there is no value for `shotArr[0].x`. The above instantiated object though will continue to loop the function method `this.detect` and throw an error for not being able to find the property:

*"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined"*

I thought I found a way of handling the error on the line I put an if statement to detect if the property was undefined?

Also once a shot is taken, the following lines of this same if statement displaying the existing property doesn't even execute because the error is being returned continually.

How can I code the `this.detect = function()` in such a way where if the object its looking for doesn't exist - it wont throw an error. And if it does exist - it returns the property I am requesting?

Comment: The error means that `shotArr[0]` is itself `undefined`.  Also your `detect()` function returns a value but nothing seems to pay attention to it.

Comment: @RandyCasburn WOW, yes that worked. And now im going to research that technique. It must be returning true or false i believe just of the top of my head but thank you. If you put it as an Answer you'll get an immediate green check.

Comment: Well, I removed the answer because you have a pretty serious design flaw. `shotArr` is clearly scoped globally and that is troubling, but has nothing to do with your question. Glad to help.

Comment: beware about returning false or the value. Because if you return [].x == 0, 0 is interpreted as false, which forces you to (double)check (as caller of detect) if return value is number or not. So as suggested in your comment, better return true or false